# WampServer 3.0.0 AH01630: client denied by server configuration:

Tags: php, apache, server

Setting up a new dev server to work on PHP7 and get some training in and run across an impasse.

I can access the server from localhost, 127.0.0.1 no problem. However when I go to another computer on the LAN. I get the dreaded:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /dev/lab.php on this server.

So just to be on the safe side I used the new interface to see how the new setup would create a vhost. The vhost works fine locally but not from another PC on the LAN. The `apache_error.log` shows:

```
  [authz_core:error] [pid 3408:tid 928] [client 192.168.1.38:54761] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp64/www/dev/lab.php
```

From everything I was reading it should have been a simple change of this

```
 <VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName dev
     DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/dev
      <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/dev/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
      </Directory>
 </VirtualHost>
```

Which you can see I changed the Require local to Require all granted. 
No JOY!

Still getting Forbidden access on the other LAN PC.

Answer (score 7):

Once I changed the localhost to all granted. The sub-directories started working. Then I could get to http://192.168.1.36/dev with no problem.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerName localhost
 DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
  <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: thanks, adding this virtual host node solved the problem. Previously, I was only able to access the site from local computer. But after adding this VirtualHost node, i am now able to access it publicly over the internet.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tips. i was stuck with WampServer Version 3.0.6 64bit access (Apache Version 2.4.23) and this code worked.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName localhost
   DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www
       <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
      </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

in case if you have changed port no of apache server you have to give same port no in below configuration. for example if your apache port no is 8080 then it you need to replace existing code in httpd-conf file

```
 <VirtualHost *:8080>
 ServerName dev
 DocumentRoot c:/wamp64/www/dev
  <Directory  "c:/wamp64/www/dev/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
```